# Can ng-app be used more than once

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, is it possible to use ng-app more than once within the same HTML content and if so, what would be a case where you would do this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **`no`** you can not have multiple `ng-app` directives in your document ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) "Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document").

But you can run multiple angular modules in your document. You will have to manually bootstrap your modules ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap))

That being said please take the time to sit back and evaluate the reasons for having multiple apps running on the same page at the same time and whether or not it makes sense for you to combine them or not.

Here is a **[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/FYAAk7XPuHbEQaH8VxCf?p=preview)** showing this working.